# Node.js container is unable to access postgres container automatically

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose, localhost

So, I have been trying to create a docker for my "project", and it was working with a simple dockerfile without stages and docker-compose. But, now I'm trying to use stages and I think my changes shouldn't affect the project like this.

When I build the docker with `docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.dev.yml up --build -d`, all the 3 services start, but the web one which containes the node stuff tries to execute my `yarn migration:run` command, which worked only in the first try, and after that all I get is:

```sh
PS C:\Users\joaov\Documents\gittin> docker logs web-dev
[INFO  wait] --------------------------------------------------------
[INFO  wait]  docker-compose-wait 2.9.0
[INFO  wait] ---------------------------
[DEBUG wait] Starting with configuration:
[DEBUG wait]  - Hosts to be waiting for: []
[DEBUG wait]  - Paths to be waiting for: []
[DEBUG wait]  - Timeout before failure: 30 seconds
[DEBUG wait]  - TCP connection timeout before retry: 5 seconds
[DEBUG wait]  - Sleeping time before checking for hosts/paths availability: 0 seconds
[DEBUG wait]  - Sleeping time once all hosts/paths are available: 0 seconds
[DEBUG wait]  - Sleeping time between retries: 1 seconds
[DEBUG wait] --------------------------------------------------------
[INFO  wait] docker-compose-wait - Everything's fine, the application can now start!
[INFO  wait] --------------------------------------------------------
yarn run v1.22.5
$ ts-node-dev ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run
[INFO] 23:26:05 ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.6 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.3.4)
Error during migration run:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '172.18.0.2',
  port: 5432
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
PS C:\Users\joaov\Documents\gittin>
```

Right now the node.js application is not running because the container is stopped, but if I run `docker start web-dev`, I get this from the log then:

```sh
[INFO  wait] --------------------------------------------------------
[INFO  wait]  docker-compose-wait 2.9.0
[INFO  wait] ---------------------------
[DEBUG wait] Starting with configuration:
[DEBUG wait]  - Hosts to be waiting for: []
[DEBUG wait]  - Paths to be waiting for: []
[DEBUG wait]  - Timeout before failure: 30 seconds
[DEBUG wait]  - TCP connection timeout before retry: 5 seconds
[DEBUG wait]  - Sleeping time before checking for hosts/paths availability: 0 seconds
[DEBUG wait]  - Sleeping time once all hosts/paths are available: 0 seconds
[DEBUG wait]  - Sleeping time between retries: 1 seconds
[DEBUG wait] --------------------------------------------------------
[INFO  wait] docker-compose-wait - Everything's fine, the application can now start!
[INFO  wait] --------------------------------------------------------
yarn run v1.22.5
$ ts-node-dev ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run
[INFO] 23:29:24 ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.6 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.3.4)
query: SELECT * FROM "information_schema"."tables" WHERE "table_schema" = current_schema() AND "table_name" = 'migrations'
query: CREATE TABLE "migrations" ("id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "timestamp" bigint NOT NULL, "name" character varying NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "PK_8c82d7f526340ab734260ea46be" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))
query: SELECT * FROM "migrations" "migrations" ORDER BY "id" DESC
0 migrations are already loaded in the database.
1 migrations were found in the source code.
1 migrations are new migrations that needs to be executed.
query: START TRANSACTION
query: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" uuid NOT NULL, "name" varchar NOT NULL, "email" varchar NOT NULL, "password" varchar NOT NULL, "admin" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), CONSTRAINT "PK_a3ffb1c0c8416b9fc6f907b7433" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))        
query: INSERT INTO "migrations"("timestamp", "name") VALUES ($1, $2) -- PARAMETERS: [1623957922252,"CreateUsers1623957922252"]
Migration CreateUsers1623957922252 has been executed successfully.
query: COMMIT
Done in 1.23s.
yarn run v1.22.5
$ ts-node-dev ./src/index.ts
[INFO] 23:29:25 ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.6 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.3.4)
PS C:\Users\joaov\Documents\gittin>
```

With that, we can see that the connection works, but it doesn't work on first try when the docker image is built...

To make it clear, I'll leave some parts of the code I think are useful directly here, and share the github repository.

**Github: https://github.com/joaocasarin/gittin**

Package.json scripts:

```json
"scripts": {
    "docker:dev": "docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.dev.yml up --build -d",
    "docker:prod": "docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml up --build -d",
    "docker:clear": "docker-compose down",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev ./src/index.ts",
    "test": "jest",
    "migration:run": "ts-node-dev ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run",
    "migration:create": "ts-node-dev ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:create",
    "entity:create": "ts-node-dev ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js entity:create",
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node ."
  }
```

You can see that when the node container starts, it waits the DB, run the migration:run and run `yarn dev` to start with ts-node-dev.

ormconfig.js:

```js
module.exports = {
    "type": "postgres",
    "ssl": process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? { rejectUnauthorized: false } : false,
    "url": process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    "entities": ["dist/entities/*.js"], // typeorm loads entities from this directory
    "migrations": ["dist/database/migrations/*.js"], // typeorm loads migrations from the directory
    "cli": {
        "migrationsDir": "src/database/migrations", // typeorm creates migrations in this directory
        "entitiesDir": "src/entities" // typeorm creates entities in this directory
    }
}
```

Dockerfile.dev:

```
FROM node:14-alpine as base
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package.json yarn.lock jest.config.ts tsconfig.json ormconfig.js ./
COPY src ./src

# used for waiting while database container is running to continue with node stuffs
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.9.0/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

FROM base as dev
WORKDIR /usr/app
ENV NODE_ENV=development
COPY --from=base /usr/app/dist/database/migrations ./
CMD /wait && yarn migration:run && yarn dev

EXPOSE 3000
```

docker-compose.dev.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
    web:
        container_name: web-dev
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        depends_on: 
            - db
        ports:
            - ${PORT}:${PORT}
        environment: 
            DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
            NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
            PORT: ${PORT}
    db:
        container_name: db-dev
        image: postgres:13.3-alpine
        restart: always
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker
            POSTGRES_DB: gittin
        ports: 
            - 5432:5432
        volumes: 
            - ./postgres-dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    pgadmin:
        container_name: pgadmin-dev
        image: dpage/pgadmin4:5.5
        restart: always
        environment: 
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: db@db.com
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: docker
            PGADMIN_PORT: 80
        ports: 
            - 8080:80
        volumes:
            - pgadmin-data-dev:/var/lib/pgadmin
        depends_on: 
            - db
volumes:
    db-data:
    pgadmin-data-dev:
```

.env:

```
PORT=3000
NODE_ENV=development
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:docker@db:5432/gittin
```

Please ask anything if needed, I really want to know how solve this problem, and also, if possible, give any advice regarding how the dockerfile and docker-compose files are written and what could I do to make it better.

Thanks

Comment: The [docker-compose-wait](https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait) tool you're using uses an environment variable `WAIT_HOSTS` to say what to wait for.  In the `web` container, does it help to set `WAIT_HOSTS: db:5432`?

Comment: Nope, just tried it and nothing happened differently. But I don't think it should, because everything was working before I separated stages in the dockerfile(I'm leaving this explicitly because it was working yesterday, and it makes no sense to not work today, since the only difference between yesterday and today is the multistage stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found part of the issue, instead having that Dockerfile.dev, on the `CMD` directive right before the `EXPOSE 3000` I changed to `CMD \wait && yarn dev`, removing the `yarn migration:run` and the application could be initialized successfully, but now I have this issue that the docker didn't run my migrations.

Now the file is:

```
FROM node:14-alpine as base
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package.json yarn.lock jest.config.ts tsconfig.json ormconfig.js ./
COPY src ./src

# used for waiting while database container is running to continue with node stuffs
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.9.0/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

FROM base as dev
WORKDIR /usr/app
ENV NODE_ENV=development
COPY --from=base /usr/app/dist/database/migrations ./
CMD /wait && yarn dev

EXPOSE 3000
```

Comment: If this is not the  correct answer and you still having issues with migrations you should not accept it as a correct answer. This would allow other people to come here and give the real solution for this problem.